# Is it impossible to have a function return a user-defined type guard?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Consider the following type and sub-types:

```
interface Animal {
  type: string;
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
  type: 'dog';
  sound: 'bark';
}

interface Cat extends Animal {
  type: 'cat';
  purpose: 'world_domination';
}
```

There's also a way to get an Animal sub-type from the value of `type`:

```
type Animals = Dog | Cat;
type AnimalFromType<T extends Animals['type']> = Extract<Animals, { type: T }>;
```

Now let's say I have an array of animals, and I want to create *a function that returns a user-defined type guard* which can then be used in an `Array.filter()` call:

```
function createFilter<T extends 'dog' | 'cat'>(type: T): (x: any) => x is AnimalFromType<T> {
  return x => x.type === type;
}
```

The problem is that it does not seem possible to have functions return type guard functions - the compiler complains with TS2322 that `(x: any) => boolean` is not assignable to `(x: any) => x is AnimalFromType<T>` - signature must be a type predicate. For some reason, the compiler does not understand that the returned boolean expression from the lambda matches the `x is AnimalFromType<T>` part of the outer function's signature.

Why is that? What would stop the compiler from understanding that `createFilter('dog')` returns a user-defined type guard (which takes an object and returns `x is Dog`)?

Edit: Full MRE provided by @jcalz here: https://tsplay.dev/wX219m

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NBeBbw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  (Anything "out of bounds" for the question should probably be removed)

Comment: The answer is going to be that the compiler only infers `boolean` as assignable to a type predicate in the specific situation where you annotate the return value of the boolean-returning function as a type predicate.  So you'd have to add an annotation like `(x): x is AnimalFromType<T> => x.type === type` to make it compile, because that's the `boolean`-returning function, not `createFilter()` (a `boolean`-returning-function-returning function, which is not the same thing). I'm happy to write up an answer but I'd like a [mre] with `animals` and `AnimalFromType` cleared up first if possible.

Comment: In explaining why the other answer doesn't seem to address the question I ended up writing what I hope is my own [mre] in [this code here](https://tsplay.dev/wX219m).  If that approach meets your needs, could you edit the question to include the setup and I'll post the answer explaining why it works with my version but not with yours?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Your MRE works and I will update the question to await your answer. I can't say I understand _why_ the compiler loses the ability to understand that the boolean expression returned from the returned lambda function represents the type guard signature of the outer function, but I guess it's simply a limitation of TS? I might ping RC about it just for my curiosity. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#14826](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14826) for an authoritative answer.

If you want the compiler to see that a `boolean` value is assignable to a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), you need to use it as the return value of a function whose [return type is explicitly annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) to be that type predicate.  That's the only method supported by the type checker.

User-defined type guards and their type predicates do not propagate in TypeScript, so any intuition you have about something like "transitivity of type predicates" is probably not going to pan out.  So you get this behavior:

```
function isString(x: any): x is string {
  return typeof x === "string"; // okay
}

function isStringMaker(): (x: any) => x is string {
  return (x: any) => typeof x === "string"; // error
}
```

because the function `(x: any) => typeof x === string` does not have an annotated return value of a type predicate type.  The compiler just infers `(x: any) => boolean` for it, and everything breaks.  There's no [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) that says "since `isStringMaker()` wants to return a function that *returns* a type predicate, we should try to interpret `typeof x === string` as such a type predicate because it's in the relevant place." Maybe such a thing could be implemented, but it isn't, and it seems this is by design to sort of require a very local and explicit expression of intent around type predicates.

To do that with `isStringMaker`, we can annotate the return type of the returned arrow function:

```
function isStringMaker(): (x: any) => x is string {
  return (x: any): x is string => typeof x === "string"; // okay
  // ----------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- return type annotation
}
```

It's not documented anywhere obvious I can find in the handbook that you can annotate the return type of an arrow function this way, but it is mentioned in ms/TS#14826 linked above, so you can at least consult that.  Anyway once you do that you don't really need to annotate the `isStringMaker()` return type anymore, since *that* will be inferred... so if you care about redundancy you can eliminate it there:

```
function isStringMaker() {
  return (x: any): x is string => typeof x === "string"; 
}
```

---

Therefore, my suggestion would be to change your `createFilter()` so that the actual type guard function has a return type annotation:

```
function createFilter<T extends 'dog' | 'cat'>(type: T) {
  return (x: any): x is AnimalFromType<T> => x.type === type;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgZSgJxmA5gCgA8AuRAQzAE8BKUw5FRFLHXRAbwChFFMBTKCExIolAA584wRPQC88xACJm2PIoDciAPRbEcANZlKnAL6dOoSLAQMMq3AFky+vpny1ERUhRqJZAPhkGJhY8Dm5eASEkL3Iqaj9A0QkpIPlZJRVWDW1dV0w4TFNzC3BoeCRUO1YnF0wAMRhCPgATd1JYnwSAoNQQ+3CefkFhTxI4mjpgrLCe5MlpOQVlUNwcnT1DYzNSqwrbVdrXRuaWgBk+FBQAJVbwFoood0HIkZjxrqm+mbY58QW0ssfutdAYjMUSjgoK5gGQIHxEABBMAwAC2ZAANi95qQfuoIVCYXCEQAROBsPiEaFgFqMZFozHY-6kADkLXJLPxPBQcHurIARmRMPpOQSwNDMLD4YgAMJkKCISnU2lIlHorFcHg4xAsiDy0U8MRCMRwFB8VkAd0KGJaAH12aicPKKqKdvNVQyMYwMmS2AAfWXyzju+nq+oFVEAFX+AB5I4qqXwaXS1ZiUABtFnzFkAXUCGQAolTMHCoDHQ2mADQcRDa+Mmfz43blGwQfjyviNDESuMJ5WMNkcxAB3X6-z4OsJTWvaJjbzxL4pz3huBR2OR-OBQgAOnd6Vr-3xOxafAgGKFCIgCGYcU9KFIFYx6Zz+KvYBv7Nw3tv6pQ2+AMDdq4+BtnwHZdhK+CDrgLLUNQ+Kfn+6JiPgn6JIgn7bjy9wJBsMYALT4YgGJwAY1ZgHAiqYAUmCIAAFq4fBAA)

Comment: Brilliant answer. Appreciate the link to the TS issue as well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a simple instanceof could solve your problem. You can use it in the array filter:

```
animals.filter(animal => animal instanceof Dog )
```

I used classes to define the types.

```
interface Animal {
  type: string;
  name: string;
}

class Cat implements Animal {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  purpose: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.type = 'cat';
    this.name = name;
    this.purpose = 'world_domination';
  }
}

class Dog implements Animal {
  type: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.type = 'dog';
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = 'bark';
  }
}

const animals = [ new Dog('dog0'), new Cat('cat0'), new Dog('dog1'), new Cat('cat1')]

console.log(animals.filter(animal => animal instanceof Dog ))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question as asked; can you explain how it addresses the question?

Comment: JHH wants to filter data from an array based on type. My code solves this problem because it will return only the objects with a specific type given in the array.filter() function. It's described in his example.

Comment: As I read it, the OP wants to "create a function that returns a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)", where such a user-defined type guard can be used in `filter()` to narrow the type of the elements in the returned array.  Like, for example, [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX219m).  What you're doing has nothing to do with user-defined type guards; you're not type guarding at all here, at least to the extent that the compiler has any idea that the filtered array contains `Dog` elements only.

Comment: As @jcalz said, this does not address the question. I am fully aware of how to narrow a type, or how to create a user-defined type guard. The question is specifically about why creating a function that _returns_ a user-defined type guard function is problematic. But thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I was really just trying to help. I can see now the difference and I even learned a little more with jcalz code.